# Is it possible to edit a file outside of my running application without closing the attached FileStream first?

Tags: c#, file-io, filestream

I have a Windows Service that's always running as a part of my application. The service uses a `TextWriterTraceListener` to write to a log file so it's easier for me to debug later if needed.

The `TraceListener` uses a `FileStream` object. I thought by using `FileShare.ReadWrite` in the construction of the `FileStream`, I would be able to edit this file in Windows Explorer as needed (edit the file and save it/rename the file/move the file), but this does not seem to be the case. The MSDN article on [`FileShare`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileshare%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states: "even if this flag is specified, additional permissions might still be needed to access the file," but is not very clear as to what those permissions might be.

As of now whenever I try to edit that file I keep running into the following error: "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."

Answer (score 1):

Two thoughts:

Regarding `FileShare` statement that additional permissions might still be needed - that's likely in reference tha while your program says it can handle someone reading or wrting to the file while it has it open, others may still need necessary access permissions (as in ACL) to access files.

The second thought is the reason you're experiencing this is probably because the other program with which you're trying to open the file is trying to open it in exclusive mode (i.e. NOT `FileShare.ReadWrite`.  So that program demands exclusive access and does not receive it because you have it open (even if willing to share).

Test with a program (or write quick one yourself where you know you're setting flag to share) that can open in shared mode to see if it works.

Comment: I checked using both Notepad and Notepad++ to open the file and saving to it. Notepad gives me the error stated in my question, while NP++ saves no problem. However, I am still having trouble renaming/deleting that file in Windows Explorer. Is that simply not possible to do without first closing the FileStream?

Answer (score 0):

To rename or remove the file, it must be opened with `FileShare.Delete`. If it is deleted or renamed while you have it open, you may find that subsequent operations on the file will fail with the error "File was removed or deleted".